# How to group,find mean and plot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, average

This may seem like a repetitive question but it's not because I have searched and searched but only get complicated solution that don't apply to my situation.
I have python data that looks as shown:

```
id | year  | sales
1  | 2010  |200
2  | 2010  |300
3  | 2011  |500
4  | 2011  |600
5  | 2012  |300
6  | 2012  |200
```

I would like to find averages for distinct years and plot the graph for the three years.

I have tried the code below but doesn't work:

```
    df.groupby(['year','sales']).count()['sales'].unstack().plot(ax=ax).show()
```

Comment: There is some error?

Comment: try this...gives the averages....groupby('year').apply(lambda x: sum(x['sales'])/len(x['sales'])).plot()

Answer (score 2):

I believe need to add `sales` after `groupby`, if necessary add `fill_value=0` to [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for replace `NaN`s to `0`:

```
df.groupby(['year','sales'])['sales'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0).plot()
```

Comment: this produces this error `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: @KMarto - What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6435 entries, 0 to 6434
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Store           6435 non-null int64
Date            6435 non-null object
Weekly_Sales    6435 non-null float64
year            6435 non-null int64
sales           6435 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 226.3+ KB
None` @jezrael

Comment: @KMarto - If change `df.groupby(['year','sales'])['sales'].count()` to `df.groupby(['year','sales'])size()` it working?

Comment: Not producing any error but just waits and ends without  showing anything

Comment: If check `df1 = df.groupby(['year','sales'])['sales'].count() to df.groupby(['year','sales']).size().unstack(fill_value=0` it return DataFrame?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179731/discussion-between-kmarto-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df[["year","sales"]].groupby("year").mean().plot()
```

You might have accidentally included "id" in the dataset.